# AngularJS $http provider not passing cookies to .NET Web Service

Tags: cookies, angularjs, http-headers

I am having problems using the $http provider in AngularJS to make an API call to a .NET backend that requires Authentication. The .NET backend service expects the ".ASPXAUTH" and "__RequestVerificationToken" cookies to be included in the call.

When I use plain JS and .ajax, passing the cookies in the beforesend block works.

```
$.ajax({
url: SERVER_URL + '/api/accounts',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
crossDomain: true,
xhrFields: {
withCredentials: true
},
success: function(data, status){
// ...
},
error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
// ...
},
beforeSend: function (req) {
    req.setRequestHeader("Cookie", REQUEST_VER_TOKEN);
    req.setRequestHeader("Cookie", ASPXAUTH_TOKEN);
}
});
```

In AngularJS, I've tried setting it in the $httpProvider and in the $http call without success:

(in the config block):

```
// ...
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common[".ASPXAUTH"] = '....';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["__RequestVerificationToken"] = '....';
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true; 
// ...
```

(in the $http call):

```
  $http({ url: 'http://SERVER_URL/api/accounts', method: 'GET',
          {headers: {
          '__RequestVerificationToken': '....',
          '.ASPXAUTH': '....'
          }}
          })
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // ...
         })
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // ...
         });
```

I get a 401 Unauthorised error. If the Authorization block is removed from the server code, the code works without needing to insert the headers. How do I emulate the same beforesend block in AngularJS and ensure that the cookies are passed to the server during the API call?

Comment: did you find the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass your header parameters not in a json object but directly into the headers attribute?

```
$http({ url: 'http://SERVER_URL/api/accounts', method: 'GET',
      headers: {
      '__RequestVerificationToken': '....',
      '.ASPXAUTH': '....'
      }
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// ...
     })
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
// ...
});
```

Hope it can help.